# Show attribute only if product is in category A

Tags: magento-1.9, php, product-attribute, onepage-checkout, category-products

Hello i am working on my Magento 1.9 checkout (order review) and i want to display the attribute "color" only if the product bought is a t-shirt but not if its something else...
Here is the code i use until now - its without the category check:

```
<?php $_item = $this->getItem() ?>
<?php $_product= Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product')->load($_item->getProductId()) ?>
<?php echo 'Artikelnummer: '.$_product->getResource()->getAttribute('COLOR')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product).'<br>'; ?>
```

But i have problems with the category check, my first approach was to set the category-ids and then check for them, if they match then display the attribute:

```
$CategoryIds = array(3,4);
$productCategory = $_product->getAvailableInCategories();
if (count(array_intersect($CategoryIds,$productCategory))) {
        $_item = $this->getItem();
$_product= Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product')->load($_item->getProductId());
echo 'Artikelnummer: '.$_product->getResource()->getAttribute('COLOR')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product).'<br>';
}
```

The problem is, that this code doesn't work - it just woun't load the last checkout step.

If someone could help me, i would be very thankfull!

Thanks,
Daniel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is simple solution for that

```
<?php $_item = $this->getItem() ?>
<?php 
$CategoryIds = array(3,4);
$_product= Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_item->getProductId());
$cats = $_product->getCategoryIds();
$showcolor=false;
foreach($cats as $cat)
{
   if (in_array($cat,$CategoryIds))
    { 
      $showcolor=true;
     }
}
if($showcolor):
 ?>
<?php echo 'Artikelnummer: '.$_product->getResource()->getAttribute('COLOR')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product).'<br>'; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution - it works with a minor improvemet -> I think there should be a "=true" behind the "if($showcolor):"

Comment: @Daniel `if($showcolor):` this condition by default  mean `$showcolor==true`

Comment: I tried to add a product that isnt in category 3 / 4, then there is no attribute (color) being showed however its showing the "Artikelnummer:" text... This is with the "=true" ---- If i do it like you said it (without the =true), there will be nothing displayed even if its in the category...

Comment: @Daniel updated code and tested too

Comment: Thank you very, very much! I tried it and it works - i will do it with some other attributes, if something wount work, i will write you here, but for now the code is working. Thank you, have a nice day!  :)